# How can I select this element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript

I am trying to write an applescript application that logs into a website upon launching. So far I can successfully open Chrome, load the web page into the active tab, select and input the password, but I cannot click the submit button.

Below is the element on the page:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn  btn--ac" alt="Login" 
   title="Login" tabindex="6"><i aria-hidden="true" 
   class="lush  lush-locked"></i> Login</button>
```

My skill level in javascript is little to none, yet I cannot find a way to successfully select this item and click it. I have tried already using the TagName and ClassName but it does not work, perhaps my syntax is incorrect. Is there a way to do this without a ID type?

I have tried:

```
execute front window's active tab javascript 
"document.getElementByClassName('btn, btn--ac').click()"

execute front window's active tab javascript 
"document.getElementByTagName('button').click()"
```

I should note this script runs in Google Chrome.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is it the only button with that class? Or the first? You can try something like `$('.btn--ac').first().click()`.

Comment: It is the only button on the whole page and the only element with the btn and btn--ac class as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're using a wrong function. It should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Try using: (Assuming the Submit button is the only button with class `btn`)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].click();
```

Here's basic definition of the function from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> document.getElementsByClassName():
>   Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names.

Hence, you get a list of elements. Hence, you select the first element in it (using the 0 as index), and then click on it.

Comment: Thank you Sarath, that was the problem! Works just as expected now!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in plain js to select an element by his class is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn--ac');
```

With this you'll get an array with all elements with the class 'btw--ac'. In your case try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn--ac')[0].click();
```